# Frying an Arduino

Tags: arduino, software

Can you brick an Arduino just through code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you can brick it without hooking up some extra hardware.  Shorting power to ground will do it.  Trying to source or drain too much power through a single pin might do it, but would be more likely to just burn out that one pin.

What you do in software shouldn't be able to actually brick the Arduino itself.  Repeated EEPROM reads/writes could burn out the EEPROM cells, but that wouldn't brick the whole thing.

Wackyvorlon is right that you can set fuses to make it impossible to program in the usual fashion.  Even that is reversible with the use of a high-voltage programmer, though.  The Arduino IDE hides the fuses from you, so this isn't too much of a worry.  Once you start programming AVRs directly or editing the boards file in the Arduino environment this can be more of an issue.

Comment: Does the ATmega328 have protections for dividing by zero or stackoverflow? The reason I ask is I'm teaching electronics, and before we do any hardware, I want to get them used to the code for microcontrollers but I don't want to wreck my Arduino if they accidently divide by zero, etc. I will be building th circuits. (For now. :) )

Answer (score 10):

You can come pretty close to bricking it using the fuses.  My understanding is that frobbed fuse settings can be corrected with a high-voltage programmer.

Answer (score 5):

While using 10 of the Decimalia units in a large sensor array, I had 2 of them from different manufacturing runs die in the course of development.  The inputs and outputs were externally opto-isolated, so it wasn't because of current or stray voltage.  I put the failures down to two possible sources.  One is that they bricked because of manufacturing failures, probably internally in the I.C.'s. The second was because it might have been possible to brick the unit by damaging the boot loader.  After the failures the units failed to be recognized as a legitimate device by the programming computer.  I still use them for sensor and data logging. I haven't had any further troubles on any other project.